# Unable to import more csv files into Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, import, csv, importexport

We have been importing products into Magento using multiple CSV files. There are files for each category. To overcome errors, we have in the past repeatedly imported the same CSV files (using Replace Complex Data). 
However, presently we can 'Check data' on a csv file but not able to import it. The loader continuously spins but never completes.

Is there any tuning? max imports? some logs to be cleared? that will help us to resume our imports again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no known limit. Probably, there is some kind of error, probably either in any modified code or in the product data.

You should open a debugging tool in your browser (i.e. Firebug or any browser built in tool). Observe the AJAX ("XHR") Request and it's answer. This will most probably give you an error message.

On the other hand, you should observe your logs: Magento logs at /var/log/, and PHP error logs on your server.